# Apache can't connect to remote MySQL, but mysql command line from same server can

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, mysql, selinux

Symptoms:

- I am running CentOS 6.
- I can connect to the remote MySQL from the command line: `mysql -h a.b.c.d -u user -p -D db`.
- Laravel artisan commands run on the local command line can also connect: `artisan migrate`.
- But the same Laravel code when running through Apache cannot connect.
- The error is: `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can’t connect to MySQL server on ‘a.b.c.d’ (13)`
- [The MySQL help on reasons for "access denied" didn't help.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/access-denied.html)

What am I doing wrong? (I am self answering for posterity.)

Answer (score 1):

To see what flags are set on httpd processes

```
getsebool -a | grep httpd
```

To allow Apache to connect to remote database through SELinux

```
setsebool httpd_can_network_connect_db 1
```

Use -P option makes the change permanent. Without this option, the boolean would be reset to 0 at reboot.

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1
```

Comment: What's the point of duplicating the answer for such an old question? Answer from bishop seems to be higher quality as it contains more explanation and not just list of commands.

Comment: This answer adds new information, specifically the _allow apache to talk to a database_ information which Bishop's answer lacks.

Answer (score 0):

The key to this problem is the `(13)`, which means "Permission Denied" (via `perror`).  Because I can connect from the command line, the permission must be in the web app.  Since I know that the credentials in the web app match the ones on the command line, the only thing left is the web server.

Via an `strace`, I discovered SELinux was blocking it.  To fix:

`sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1`

This permanently sets SELinux to allow network connections out of httpd.

Comment: You can solve the related problem of Apache not sending emails, while the command line can, with: `setsebool -P httpd_can_sendmail=1`